# Calculate amount between period

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help please !!!

how to calculate the PayedManualAmount by period, the period is between Disbursement.
so in the second Disbursement(325) i have to obtain 5
in third Disbursement(500) i have to obtain 7 and so on..

```
if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Amount') IS NOT NULL)
    drop table #Amount

create table #Amount
(
    Date                smalldatetime,
    Disbursement        decimal(18,2),
    PayedManualAmount   decimal(18,2),
    ForPayAmount        decimal(18,2)
)


INSERT INTO #AmountForPay(Date,Disbursement,PayedManualAmount,ForPayAmount) 
VALUES
('20121226',    675.00  ,NULL   ,8.37),
('20121226',    NULL    ,5.00   ,0.00),
('20121227',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20121228',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20130323',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20130324',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20130325',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20130326',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20130327',    325.00  ,NULL   ,4.03),--ForPayAmount = SUM(PayedManualAmount) between 2012-12-26 and 2013-03-26 = 5
('20130328',    NULL    ,4      ,0.00),
('20130329',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20140228',    NULL    ,3      ,0.00),
('20140301',    NULL    ,NULL   ,0.00),
('20140302',    500.00  ,NULL   ,6.20), --ForPayAmount = SUM(PayedManualAmount) between 2013-03-27 and 2014-03-01 = 7
```

Comment: your question needs a review. "between Disbursement" does not make sense. You should say "between a and b". Where does the 325 in "The second disbursement (325)" comes from? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't tested (I don't even know if it's syntactically correct as I wrote it out of SSMS), but something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @LastProcessedID INT
SELECT @LastProcessedID = 0

WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentID = ID
    FROM #Amount
    WHERE ID > @CurrentID
    AND Disbursement IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ID

    IF @@RowCount = 0 BREAK;

    UPDATE #Amount
    SET ForPayAmount = (SELECT SUM(PayedManualAmount)
                        FROM #Amount
                        WHERE ID < @CurrentID
                        AND ID > @LastProcessedID)
    WHERE ID = @CurrentID

    SELECT @LastProcessedID = @CurrentID
END
```

Note that you'll need to add an ID column to your temp table. You could perhaps use your date column for this, but I'd personally just add an identity column.